# How to check if mouse is on a shpae in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am building a simple flash game in AS3 and I was wondering if I could use code similar to "hitTestPoint()" except it applies to a shape and not a symbol?

The maze is simply a line shape, so if the ball moves off the shape then the game is terminated. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: How many different lines is the maze made up of? Would it be impractical to separate walls into being their own symbols?  This way you could loop through them all in an array to test for collisions.

Comment: Check out Grant Skinner's great collision detection class:  https://github.com/gskinner/AS3Libs/tree/master/CollisionDetection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough.  Just test if the maze is found at the current location of the ball.

```
function test():Boolean {
    // First we get the absolute coordinates of the ball
    var loc:Point = ball.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
    // Next we collect all the DisplayObjects at that coordinate.
    var stack:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(loc);
    var found:Boolean = false;

    // Now we cycle through the array looking for our maze
    for each (var item in stack) {
        if (item.name == "mazeShape") {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

If you're really interested in whether the mouse (and not the ball) is off the maze, just replace the first line with this:

```
var loc:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending how your game looks, you could also use coordinates for this.

Just tell the game if Player > 100 Y it is off the game it's limits = Restart.

It might won't be the most solid solution but it is definetely a way to solve it as I don't believe there is a function for it, please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Would work to test if it's hitting a simple box shape but not a maze made up of many box/rectangle shapes.

Answer (score 0):

The [AS3 Collision Detection Kit](https://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/) will let you detect hits based on color if separating the maze into smaller symbols is not appropriate.